# Textarea preview

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem regarding `textarea` and text previewing. It doesn't recognize `Enter` button as a newline character. Any ideas how to make this previewing correctly?

[image]

**EDIT :**

[image]

I want this text automatically change line when it's not fitting instead of h-scroll.

**Answer :**

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: are you rendering markdown for the preview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<pre>` tag while printing text from `textarea` it will reflect all your new lines as it is entered text in `textarea`

Just use `<pre>` before content.e.g.

```
<pre> Text Content From text Area</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about this tag.

Comment: Though I still have a minor problem. Text automatically being hidden when  I type more than a row. Acts like `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Found the answer. `white-space:pre-wrap` solved the issue

Comment: just set the width of text area or you can control through `cols` and `rows` attributes of text area.

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/gZM1173PNweJzcBEutTw?p=preview

You need to use `ngSanitize` and allow you parameter to accept html entry with $sce.trustAsHtml();

html

```
<textarea ng-model="text" ng-change="change()"></textarea>
<p ng-bind-html='text'></p>
```

js

```
$scope.change = function(){ 

    $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.text);
}
```

css

```
{white-space: pre}
```

You'll be able to render and save your text with newline